# PowerBI: RELATEDTABLE (Newbie Q)

Tags: powerbi

Just wondering what is the diff between:

```
T2 = RELATEDTABLE(T1)
```

vs.

```
T2 = T1
```

Both seem to create reference to the original table, so is there circumstances to use the first way?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `RELATEDTABLE` you are not looking at the entire referenced table, but a subset according to your current row context and established relationship. In simple terms it is used on the one-side of a relationship to access the related rows in the many-side.

It's actually a shortcut for `CALCULATETABLE` without any further logical expression, so it's handy if you don't want to apply e.g. additional filtering or other semantics available to `CALCULATETABLE`.

Let's assume your tables look like this, where there is a one-many relationship between the tables on the aptly named `KEY` column. The tables describe a small store with a physical and online presence, and the store has four sales of products with varying price and quantity of sales:

`Fact_Table`:

| KEY | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 |

`Dim_Table`:

| KEY | Desc |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Physical Store |
| 2 | Online Store |

You can now use `RELATEDTABLE` to calculate e.g. total sales per store type, as a column in `Dim_Table`:

```
Total Sales = 
SUMX ( 
    RELATEDTABLE ( Fact_Table ) , 
    [Price] * [Quantity] 
)
```

Your resulting table would look like this:

| KEY | Desc | Total Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Physical Store | 7 |
| 2 | Online Store | 16 |

Using just the table reference would not invoke the necessary context transition to apply the row context in `Dim_Table` as a filter on `Fact_Table`, meaning that you would scan the entire `Fact_Table` for each row in your `Dim_Table`, resulting in this (erroneous) result:

```
Total Sales (WRONG) = 
SUMX ( 
    Fact_Table ,
    [Price] * [Quantity]
)
```

| KEY | Desc | Total Sales (WRONG) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Physical Store | 23 |
| 2 | Online Store | 23 |